# How do I forward particular logs under a directory using rsyslog?

Tags: linux, rhel, logs, rsyslog

Trying to froward following logs from `/home/ddlog/ms/logs/execution_logs/_abc-xyz-ms_*` to VMware vRealize Log Insight using rsyslog. For some reason that does not seem to be working.

I have tried using imfile -

```
# Now load the external log
$InputFileName /home/ddlog/ms/logs/execution_logs/_abc-xyz-ms_*
$InputFileTag ddlog
$InputFileStateFile ms
$InputFileSeverity debug
$InputFileFacility local7
$InputRunFileMonitor
local7.*  @@hostname:514
```

Commenting out the imfile and updating the rsyslog.conf with the

```
*.* @@remote-host:514
```

seems to work perfectly fine but I am more concerned about forwarding specific logs.

Comment: The last sentence is unclear. Do you mean rsyslog already has the log messages? If so, please check where `/home/ddlog/ms/log/...` is created/written to in rsyslog.conf. Once we know this, the solution may be very simple.

Comment: No, what I meant was using the default syntax " *.*     @@hostname:514" I am able to see the boot.log, cron logs, mail logs and /var/log/messages as well which have been configured in rsyslog.conf but when I create a imfile to forward abc-xyz-ms* logs under execution_logs it does not work.

Comment: If you are using legacy format you probably need to add as first line: `$ModLoad imfile`

Comment: I have imfile added under load modules -
# Then load modules:
 $ModLoad imuxsock.so
 $ModLoad imklog.so
 $ModLoad imfile

However I have made the change and add it as first line as well which does not seems to help.

Comment: If you are just testing and not adding new data to the files you should remove the state files. `InputFileStateFile` is deprecated I think. It might not work for a glob where many files cannot use the same state file. Try removing that config line. Check for syntax errors with `rsyslogd -N 1`. You can get lots of debug output with `-dn` which might provide a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without the relevant syslog content. But, my guess would be file permission issues as rsyslog drops permissions to `syslog` and you are trying to track `/home/ddlog/..` path.

If so then there are a couple of ways around that like adding `syslog` user to the `ddlog` user group.